# wp_nonce_field not being validated

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I have a form in my WordPress site (4.9.1) that includes a nonce field (with wp_nonce_field()) and that posts to admin-post.php.

I use it in a very simple way...:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( $action, 'referer' ); ?>
```

...That generates something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="referer" name="referer" value="d6dd8e58dd" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/slug/?laorder=99371&amp;laid=92bbfca59e41a4938ce8c0751cfcd0c4a68e75c14bd94b981505cc037079280&amp;lauser=myemail%domain.com" />
```

The problem is about validation:

```
if (! isset( $_POST['referer'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['referer'], $action ) )
```

fails under some (unknown) circumstances: it seems to work always when posting in incognito mode, and it fails randomly for some users with different browsers (chrome, firefox or safari).

All users are guests.

Does anybody knows why this *random* behavior is happening?

Answer (score 2):

as you said all users are guests and none of them is logged in but You should not use nonce for non logged in users. You should not use nonces in any full or partial page caching scenario. Unlike the impression given many times, just sprinkling nonce here and there with no specific reason do not improve the sites security, and may cause actual problems for non logged in users.

because WordPress will validate your authentication cookie information and if you're allowed to delete that post will proceed to delete it. What an attacker can do with this is make your browser go to that url without your knowledge. For example by crafting a link on a 3rd party page. For example having:

```
<img src="http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=trash" />
```

In it. This would trigger your browser to make a request to WordPress, the browser would automatically attach your authentication cookie and WordPress would consider this a valid request.

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)